# Linq select where in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class

```
public class Group
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and 2 lists `List<string> groupRestrict` and `List<Group> groups`

now the group list contains some groups with all fields filled in and I want to select all the restricted groups, the groupRestrict list contains just the name of the groups.

I tried some things, but for some reasons, it always returns an empty list. this as my last test:

`var lst = groups.Where(j => groupRestrict.Contains(j.Name)).ToList();`

Any clue what might be going wrong?

**Edit:** Like the comments said, this should have worked, it was the input that had some `'` but now I would like to have that the groupRestrict doesn't have to be the exact name, but can use 'like' features.

current expression:

`var restrictedGroups = (from gr in groupRestrict join g in groups on gr equals g.Name select g).ToList();`

Comment: Be aware that this is a bigO - rather do this query on a HashSet (or Dictionary) and think about using `.Join` or `.GroupJoin` (whether you want a left or full join)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair it's not on a SQL database, if that is what you are refering to :)

Comment: This should work. Be aware that string comparison is case sensitive by default.

Comment: Kiwi, no. @AndreasNiedermair means `Join` function in LINQ.

Comment: Sounds like it should work (albeit relatively inefficiently if `groupRestrict` is large) - please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: As written by others, normally it's better to have a `HashSet<string> groupRestrict`, so that the single comparison is O(1) and the whole work is O(n) instead of being O(n^2)

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev & @AndreasNiedermair: Would the join be something like: `(from gr in groupRestrict join g in groups on gr equals g.Name select g).ToList();`

Comment: Also keep in mind that string comparison is case sensitive in C#.

Comment: @xanatos, contrary to what Microsoft claims in the msdn here http://goo.gl/X1zueG Retrieving a value by using its key is not close to O(1), whatever "close" means, **it's O(ln(n))**. Sorry for being a CS-nazi about that, I just wanted to get this straight :o)

Comment: @Orace I've always found written that the complexity of retrieving a key in an HashSet (and a Dictionary is an HashSet with a Value) is O(1). But I'm not a CS expert.

Comment: @Orace http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table The average complexity of Search is given as O(1), with worst case O(n) (probably of an Hash table full of collisions)

Comment: @xanatos, you are definitely right about this, and msdn too (sic). HashTable are not search trees and I'm an idiot which should return to his books. Thank you ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var lst = groups.Where(j => groupRestrict.Any(x=> j.Name.Contains(x))).ToList();
```

this would match all groups with names that contain one or more strings from the searchList.

Case insensitive variant would be:

```
var lst = groups.Where(j => groupRestrict.Any(x=> j.Name.ToLower().Contains(x.ToLower()))).ToList();
```

Allthough it would be better to convert the groupRestrict to lowercase prior to the query in this case and you can omit the .ToLower() call for x:

```
string[] lowerCaseGroupRestrict = groupRestrict.Select(x=> x.ToLower()).ToArray();
var lst = groups.Where(j => lowerCaseGroupRestrict.Any(x=> j.Name.ToLower().Contains(x))).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice thanks! The groupRestrict is a user input (although it's get checked and filtered first) . so the prior can be easy called :)

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot it! :)